# What documents should I always carry with me in Hungary?

Tags: identification

I'm an EU citizen (Italy) living in a foreign country (Hungary), I have a residence permit for the aforementioned country.

When I received the residence permit they gave me the following documents/cards:

1. **Lakcímet Igazoló Hatósági Igazolvány** (red-green card)
2. **Regisztrációs Igazolás EGT-állampolgár Részére** (yellow card)

I also own an hungarian **driving license**, and the **Hatósági Igazolvány** (white card).

Of course, I also own the identity card of my home country, and a passport too.

Given I would like to carry with me (while I walk and drive on the hungarian soil) the least amount of documents/cards, what are the ones I definitely need to carry with me?

---

Below I'm reporting some of my findings, they may or may not be correct so please correct me if I'm wrong:

- With my limited knowledge of the hungarian language I figured out I don't necessarily need to carry with me the *white card*, I just need to remember/provide its 9-digits number when required (at family doctor, hospitals, etc);
- I also realize I'll need to carry with me the *driving license* anytime I want to drive the car, along with the circulation documents of the car (that I can't never leave in the car);
- It looks like anytime I need to present the *red-green card* I'll also need to show the *yellow card*, because somehow they complete each other;

Comment: The first is an: [Official card certifying address and personal identity](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/HUN-HO-10001/index.html) ; the second is a [Residence document issued to European Union citizens](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/HUN-HO-04001/index.html): **Valid together with the travel document used to enter** ; since these doesn't contain a photo and the second is only valid with your identity card. probably all 3.

Comment: @MarkJohnson why wouldn't just my italian ID be enough considered both countries are part of the schengen area?

Comment: @FezVrasta, Schengen should not matter here, other EU treaties do.

Comment: The first is also issued to Hungarians, probably as proof of place of residence. The second proves that that you have fullfilled the conditions of the **Article 8 (1) Freedom of Movement**. [DIRECTIVE 2004/58/EC - Article 8 - Administrative formalities for Union citizens](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex:32004L0038R%2801%29#d1e716-): **1. Without prejudice to Article 5(5), for periods of residence longer than three months, the host Member State may require Union citizens to register with the relevant authorities.**

Comment: It's a good idea to have the drivers license on you even if not driving anyway, because you might need to drive someone elses's car. (dedicated driver etc)

Comment: I suggest broadening your thought process a bit: a) What documents are you legally required to carry, b) what happens if you get caught without and how likely is it that someone wants to see it, c) what's the risk of a document getting lost or stolen, d) how hard & expensive is it to replace them.  Make your choices based on this assessment. Example: I was a US Green Card for over 10 years, but never carried it other than for international travel. No one ever wants to see your green card and it's hugely expensive and cumbersome to replace.

Answer (score 1):

https://helsinki.hu/wp-content/uploads/overview_IDchecks_Hungary.pdf

> In course of an ID check the police officer requests the identity card or any other document certifying
> the identity of the person subject to the measure.

> Personal identity is verified primarily by the identity card; also any other document may be accepted
> by which the identity of the checked person may be determined with credibility. The Police Officer
> may also accept the statement of a person known to him or another person of verified identity who is
> present at the ID check.

> In course of an identity check the identity of a person has to be established and, where this is
> required for further action or measures or by other circumstances, the particulars of the person
> involved have to be recorded on an Identity-check Sheet. The Identity-check Sheet contains the
> following data:
> a) the family- and given names of the person (for women, also the maiden name);
> b) date and place of birth;
> c) mother's maiden name;
> d) address details (home, temporary residence);
> e) serial mark and number of Identity Card or other identity document;
> f) place, time and reason for the identity check

Now let's see what docs you need and why:

1. Either your passport or your Hungarian driving license is absolutely required. I would use the Hungarian one for the sake of simplicity.
2. I like my life being simple and so I would keep the address (red-green) card with me. It's not strictly necessary but ... uh do you want to make the life of police harder or easier? Especially as a foreigner in Orbán's Hungary, if you get what I mean. This is why I would have the yellow card with me, too.
3. Hatósági Igazolvány (white card) I was scratching my head here, but I think you mean the health card https://frsz.hu/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/taj-kartya.png ? Well, the police won't care but if you need medical attention, you will need it.